# Routing with React Router v4 in embedded React Apps

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I builded a little questionnaire with React and React-router v4.
I developed with create-react-app. 
It is working fine when I build it as standalone page. The Router routes like I want.

But now I made a build for a page in Mahara (https://mahara.org/) and another one for Wordpress.

In Mahara it is a plugin and the questionnaire comes in a part of the Mahara page.
In Wordpress the questionnaire is a part of the whole Wordpress Page.

In both variants the router doesn't work. The path "/" is not found. So the default "not found" page appears.

I edited the homepage property in the package.json and the basename attribute for the BrowserRouter.

Is it generally possible to make the router functioning, when the React app is not a standalone page?

Maybe the problem is, that in both platforms(Mahara/Wordpress) the url is not really the one where the questionnaire exists?

In mahara for example the questionnaire exists in "http://mahara_17_10.local/blocktype/learningstyle/js/build/" but the url shows: "http://mahara_17_10.local/view/view.php?id=3842". This public page is generated with Smarty templating and some php.

I tried both: The real place, where the React build folder exists, or the generated url (the second one). But I had no luck so far.

here some code:
package.json:

```
"homepage": "http://mahara_17_10.local/view/view.php?id=3842",
```

BrowserRouter:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/view/view.php?id=3842">
```

Router in Main Component:

```
<div className={ApplicationClassNames}>
                    <ApplicationHeader
                        title={title}
                        count_blocks={count_blocks}
                        number_of_blocks_overall={number_of_blocks_overall}
                    />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
                        <ApplicationBody
                            page_now={page_now}
                            count_cats={count_cats}
                            count_pages={count_pages}
                            categories_pages_quantity={categories_pages_quantity}
                            catValuesCountAll={catValuesCountAll}
                            language={language}
                            show_result={false}
                            values_not_for_categories={values_not_for_categories}
                        />
                        )}/>
                        <Route path='/wtf' component={Result} />
                        <Route><div>Not found</div></Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
```

So my questions are:

1: Is it generally possible to make the router functioning, when the React app is not a standalone page?

2. If yes, how for excample in wordpress or mahara. Maybe anybody knows a tutorial oder something else what can help me here.

I would be very happy, if somebody could help me here a little bit.
thanx =)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you find an answer? If yes, can you please write an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

@ Learner

If you have a Moodle Plugin (as a  react application) on a public page for example, and the url is : moodlepage.de/mod/learningstyle/view.php?id=27
you can put an .htaccess file in the root folder of moodle with the following content:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mod/learningstyle/view.php/(.*)$ /mod/learningstyle/view.php?id=27 [QSA,L]
```

This tells the webserver to look at /mod/learningstyle/view.php?id=27 when you type mod/learningstyle/view.php/green for eyample. So the page is called and react has its url with the paramters.

This is the minimal configuration of the htaccess. You can put there rewrite conditions and some other stuff.  But this works.
The (.*)$ is for the router paramters. They work too.
Make sure you have Allowoverride All in your virtual host or whereever you have your settings for the webserver.
This works fine in moodle and mahara. Worpress has its own htaccess with some rewriterules, so it didnt work for me. See here:

[React Router v4 and htaccess with wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948444/react-router-v4-and-htaccess-with-wordpress/48948505#48948505)