# React Router v4 and htaccess with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, .htaccess, react-router

I made a simple React App with two components, which can route by links from one component to the other. If the page is standalone it works well. With the links inside the app the components can be switched and changing the url changes the components well, too. The parameters in the URL are working, too.
But now I want to integrate it in Wordpress as a plugin. The plugin works and the react app is schown on the wordpress page. The router works inside the app. But it`s not possible to switch between the components if I change the url.
I know this is a problem with the correct configuration of the .htaccess file.
The original .htacces of wordpress looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The name of the page where the react app is shown is "shorttest". So I tried to add the RewriteRule:
RewriteRule ^shorttest/(.*)$ /shorttest [QSA,L]

or

RewriteRule ^shorttest/(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]

and I deleted the [L] in the rules above.

But this is not working.

here the important files from the the react app:

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/shorttest">
       <App/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Blue.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Blue.css';
import { withRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const BlueComponent = withRouter(props => <Blue {...props} />);
class Blue extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.match);
        return (
            <div className="Blue">
                <header className="blue__header">
                    <nav className="BluelicationHeader__nav">
                        <ul className="BluelicationHeader__ul">
                            <li className="BluelicationHeader__li">
                                <Link className="Blue__a" to='/green'>Green</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                <div className="bluebackground">
                    <img className="blue__image" src={require(`./image/difficulty_3.png`)} alt="image"/>
                </div>
                <p className="Blue-intro">
                    parameter was {this.props.match.params.param}
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default BlueComponent;
```

Green.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Green.css';
import { withRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const GreenComponent = withRouter(props => <Green {...props} />);
class Green extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Green">
                <header className="Green__header">
                    <nav className="GreenlicationHeader__nav">
                        <ul className="GreenlicationHeader__ul">
                            <li className="GreenlicationHeader__li">
                                <Link className="Green__a" to='/'>Blue</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                <p className="Green-intro">
                    To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default GreenComponent;
```

package.json

```
"homepage": "http://wp_react_router.local/wp-content/plugins/shortcode-test/js/build",
```

Does anybody know what I have to do in the htaccess or maybe in another htaccess?

Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for angular router:

In wordpress theme or plugin you need in functions.php (where you add the styles and js. it has the name of the plugin) a function, which overides the htaccess. So you don`t need any changes in the htaccess file itself.

Excample:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic_angularApp');

function custom_rewrite_basic_angularApp() {
    require 'config.php';
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^'. $wordpressShortcodePageName. '\/(.*)\/?',
        'index.php?pagename='. $wordpressShortcodePageName,
        'top'
    );
}
```

$wordpressShortcodePageName must be the name of the page.
Now the angular router works perfectly. It is not tested with react router, but I think it is the same problem so it should work.

Please let us know, if it works.H

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on Vue.js, meeting the same problem.

I've now found a solution: you can dump `(new \WP_Rewrite())->rewrite_rules()` to get all the WP route rules (with Regex), as for vue-router, the Regex can be used to set dynamic routes directly.

Currently I'm working on it and I'll share my code here when the work is done.

The rewrite_rules dump just like this

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would really not fool with Wordpress' .htaccess file.  Rather, I would store routing inside your React component and not use the URL at all.

Here is a pretty good answer for how to do that:

[React Router Without Changing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721812/react-router-without-changing-url)

Think about what you would do if you had 2 React components on the same page?  You would not want to use URL routing then, either.

The other option would be to use something like Redux and handle routing yourself if it's only 2 components.

Comment: Ok, but that would mean that there is no chance to present a specific component of the app with an url or to use the browser navigation in a react app in wordpress? If so, it would make me sad.

Comment: Hey @fricko did you find a resolution for this? I'm finding that the WP htaccess is messing with react router url links I'm trying to use in a subdirectory.

Comment: See my solutin I described above. It should work for react, too.